# What species is this fly? Look like mosquito with unusually long legs

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, mosquitoes

I found this in Bangalore, India. It looks exactly like a mosquito but with extremely long legs, first I confused it with long legged spider (which are common here) but it's not, Can someone tell me what it is?[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, the insect is too small and blurry in the picture to make out. For ID we ideally need several high quality photos of the organism of interest. Having said that, looks like it might be a crane fly.

Comment: Crane flies look like larger, long-legged cousins of mosquitoes, but are beneficial insects, and harmless to humans. Look for pictures of crane flies in your region and see if it resembles te critter you saw before it became...smooshed.